# How to make sure NSolve gives all solutions in a given range?

Tags: equation-solving

When I input the system of equations:

```
Block[{p, a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, 
      NSolve[{2*p == 2*p*a + (1 - 2 p)*b,
              a == (p)*d + 2*(p^2) + ((1/2) - p)*(b + c),
              b == (2*(p^2)) + ((1/2) - p)*(a + c) + p*g,
              c == ((1 - 2 p)/3)*(f + b + d) + (2*p/3)*(e + g + a),
              d == p + p*a + (1/2 - p)*(e + c),
              e == p + (1/2 - p)*(d + c) + p*f,
              f == p*e + (1/2 - p)*(g + c),
              g == p*b + (1/2 - p)*(c + f),
              0.5 >= p >= 0}
      ]
]
```

I get the solutions with $ p = 0.5 $ and $ p = 0 $. However, there is definitely a set of solutions for $ p = 0.25 $ as if I put $ p = 0.25 $ instead of $ 0.5 > p > 0 $ in I get a set of solutions. However, [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) is not giving this solution to me automatically, and I was wondering if there might be others that I was missing and if there was any way to make sure I got these solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqns = {2*p == 2*p*a + (1 - 2 p)*b, 
   a == (p)*d + 2*(p^2) + ((1/2) - p)*(b + c), 
   b == (2*(p^2)) + ((1/2) - p)*(a + c) + p*g, 
   c == ((1 - 2 p)/3)*(f + b + d) + (2*p/3)*(e + g + a), 
   d == p + p*a + (1/2 - p)*(e + c), e == p + (1/2 - p)*(d + c) + p*f, 
   f == p*e + (1/2 - p)*(g + c), g == p*b + (1/2 - p)*(c + f), 1/2 >= p >= 0};
```

Although `NSolve[eqns]` returns a result, the documentation specifies that the variables should be given. Doing so produces results with `p` having the values `{0, 1/4, 1/2}`.

```
sol = NSolve[eqns, {p, a, b, c, d, e, f, g}] /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x] //
   Union

(* {{p -> 0, a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0, e -> 0, f -> 0, g -> 0}, {p -> 1/4, 
  a -> 8/15, b -> 7/15, c -> 1/2, d -> 2/3, e -> 19/30, f -> 11/30, 
  g -> 1/3}, {p -> 1/2, a -> 1, b -> 2/3, c -> 2/3, d -> 1, e -> 2/3, 
  f -> 1/3, g -> 1/3}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqns /. sol

(* {{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, 
  True, True, True, True, True, True}, {True, True, True, True, True, True, 
  True, True, True}} *)
```

Comparing with the results from [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
sol2 = Solve[eqns, {p, a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, Reals]

(* {{p -> 0, a -> 0, b -> 0, c -> 0, d -> 0, e -> 0, f -> 0, g -> 0}, {p -> 1/4, 
  a -> 8/15, b -> 7/15, c -> 1/2, d -> 2/3, e -> 19/30, f -> 11/30, 
  g -> 1/3}, {p -> 1/2, a -> 1, b -> 2/3, c -> 2/3, d -> 1, e -> 2/3, 
  f -> 1/3, g -> 1/3}} *)

sol == sol2

(* True *)
```